# Trying to remove records in query with IF statement and calculated column

Tags: mysql, database, scripting

I have been given the following problem:

When a donation needs to be picked up, the transportation costs de-value the donation by 10%. Write a SELECT statement that includes the donors first name and last name, the donation description, the donation value and a calculated column named actual_value that displays the donation value minus the 10% transportation charge. The results should only show donations that had to picked up

I can get the calculation correctly but the problem states to only return donations that had to be picked up (value would be 1 in this case)

I have tried an IF function and a sub query

```
USE donations;
SELECT donor_first, donor_last, donation_desc, donation_value, IF(pickup_req = 0, donation_value - (donation_value * 0.10), donation_value) AS actual_value
FROM donor d JOIN donation do ON d.donor_id = do.donor_id
```

When it returns it should only show values in the pickup row what are 1, currently it is showing all (1 and 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need `where` clause to filter out `picked_req > 0`

```
select donor_first, donor_last, donation_desc, donation_value, donation_value - (donation_value * 0.10) as actual_value 
from donor d 
join donation do on d.donor_id = do.donor_id
where coalesce(d.pickup_req, 0) > 0
```

Comment: This helped me think although it was not the answer. I was overthinking. The answer was: USE donations;
SELECT donor_first, donor_last, donation_desc, donation_value, IF(pickup_req = 1, donation_value - (donation_value * 0.10), donation_value) AS actual_value
FROM donor d JOIN donation do ON d.donor_id = do.donor_id WHERE pickup_req =1

Comment: I have never see the coalesce function before though, that is interesting and it also works to find those values but they are not distinct